# jQuery: Ignore jsonp parsererror and use the raw data

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, jsonp, parse-error

I get a JSONP parser error when I make a GET cross-domain request with jQuery. The frustrating thing is, that the output of the request is a valid json. Unfortunately when I change dataType-setting to json, the request fails all together and nothing is returned.

*My question is*: How can I keep making a jsonp cross-domain request and just get the output as RAW text to a (error)function. I can convert the result myself.

Thanks!

Comment: answer to question is no. You can see the `json` data in console, but it is not `jsonp` so browser security prevails. Use a proxy to retrieve it

Comment: There is no way to do something like this with web sockets or something?

Comment: can set up a proxy on your server in a few minutes, or third party like Yahoo YQL

Comment: The problem is that only the user which uses the web app can make the request. But I think this might be a security issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: why would it be any more of security issue than making request to domain you can't get data from already? This is nothing new... there are 20 posts a week here about making cross domain requests

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation where a service I was trying to get data from was returning invalid JSON

I worked around the problem like this:

```
$.ajax( request with dataType set as text )
.done(function (data) {
    var rawJSON = data.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');
    var response = JSON.parse(rawJSON);
    // do what you were going to do here
});
```